# ruby on rails / routing-filter / form_for changes html

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, routes, filter, form-for

this question is related to routing-filter.

I have this in my view:

```
<% form_for :post, :url => {:action => "show"} do |f| %>
```

which translates in the browser to this:

```
<form action="/en/posts/show" method="post">
```

after changing the `I18n.locale` e.g.

```
I18n.locale = :en
```

the html becomes:

```
<form action="/en/posts/72" method="post">
```

and the action is not working and I get this error:

> Unknown action
>
> No action responded to 72.

Sure, there is no action like 72. This number is the show action's input of course. And it is correct post number. So if I put this address localhost:3000/en/posts/72 to the browser, then it gives me the page without a problem.

So why it doesn't work in the form then?

Thanks.

Comment: Why are you posting to the show action?

Comment: Why not?
The default show action's code from the scaffolding has the
      @post = Post.find( params[:id],...
so it should take the id right?

Comment: POSTing implies sending data to update an object.  Show retrieves an object for display and a GET request is sufficient and RESTful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Specify a method like that:

```
<% form_for :goal, :url => { :action => 'show' }, :html => {:method => :put} do |f| %>
```

It worked for me.